# Can you go to specific step within Angular IntroJS event?

Tags: angular, intro.js

It seems if I try to go to a particular step from within the IntroJS `onexit` event, it gets very confused and doesn't show the correct step and highlighted element.

I have my steps setup via json, i have 8 steps

```
[{
    element:
    title:
    intro:
}]
```

If the user closes the tour by clicking the X (skip) button, I need to show a final message, so I have set it up to go to a specific step via the `onexit`

```
 introJS.onexit(() => {
    introJS.goToStep(8).start();
 }
```

Can we not do it here ? Basically what happens is it shows the correct intro text but its highlighting a completely different element from a different step. Is this because I'm calling itself within the event ?
How would one go about doing this if possible ?

I have even tried setting the options to a new set of steps - and splicing those steps to only include the single step I need - this does not work either.

```
introJs.setOptions({
    steps: this.steps[lastStep]
});
introJs.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @GRD I was able to solve this by instead using the `onbeforeexit` event and making sure to return false as such

```
introJs.onbeforeexit(() => {
   introJs.goToStepNumber(lastStep).start();
   introJs.refresh(true);
   return false;
}
```